Error in executing in between sql statement
I have this springboot application, the ibatis dao mapper class is as below.
<select id="selectSiccCodeList" parameterType="java.lang.Integer" resultMap="siccCodeList">
    select sic_code, sic_code_desc
    from sat_sicc_msic 
    where min <![CDATA[<=]]> #{msicCode,jdbcType=BIGINT} and max <![CDATA[>=]]> #{msicCode,jdbcType=BIGINT}
</select>

in postgresql, this work.
select * from sat_sicc_msic where min <= 1299 and max>=1299 
when i run my application i get this error
org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is 
org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException:
### Error querying database.  Cause: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
### The error may exist in class path resource [com/pingan/imp/sat/core/sf/mapper/SiccMsicMapper.xml]
### The error may involve com.pingan.imp.sat.core.sf.mapper.SiccMsicMapper.selectSiccCodeList
### The error occurred while handling results
### SQL: select sic_code, sic_code_desc         from sat_sicc_msic          where min  <=  ? and max  >=  ?
### Cause: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

